# Wildfly Error: Error MEM sending ENABLE-APP

Tags: wildfly, load-balancing, httpd.conf, wildfly-10

Getting following exception in wildfly:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.modcluster] (UndertowEventHandlerAdapter - 1): 
MODCLUSTER000042: Error MEM sending ENABLE-APP command to rod.de.mgg.dk/11.10.11.11:400, configuration will be reset: MEM: Can't update or insert host alias
```

- Able to ping this server.
- Deployed an application in server but even after undeploy and restart not able to fix it.
- Wildfly server group has 3 nodes in it which balance load.

The only response to this i found is following on google:

```
The indicates a problem with the LB, please inspect apache/undertow logs for the cause.
```

But i am unable to deduce so. Could anyone please suggest more here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase `MaxHost` in your `httpd.conf` as per your backend server requirement.